# How do I make sure to removeObserver without subclassing and overrideing dealloc?

Tags: ios, memory-management, nsnotificationcenter

When using the [NSNotificationCenter object](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), if you add an observer for a notification, `You must invoke removeObserver: or removeObserver:name:object: before any object specified by addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: is deallocated`.

Is there a way to do this without subclassing the object and overriding "dealloc"? I don't want to have to subclass a bunch of objects just to use notifications with them if I can avoid it. Is there some other way to learn about the dealloc before it happens?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How you do this depends on what the objects are, and how they're being deallocated. Can you be a little more specific about what you're trying to do?

Comment: The object is just a UIView that gets allocated and deallocated as appropriate during evaluation. It might be deallocated when its view controller is destroyed, or it might happen earlier.

Comment: If it happens earlier, how is it being deallocated? Can't you call removeObserver wherever you're causing that view to be deallocated?

Comment: Strikes me as far more prudent to do it in `dealloc` because that way you don't have to anticipate every possible way that the view might be deallocated. If you have to do this for a bunch of different `UIView` objects, create a `UIView` subclass that has this notification logic and then use that class rather than `UIView` wherever you need this functionality.

Comment: Rob is correct - I don't want to have to add a whole bunch of handling code everywhere that it might be deallocated. Problem is, what if I want to add this handling to a UIView in one place and a UIButton in another? I don't want to have to make up some ridiculous subclass just to add this to UIButton.

Comment: How do you add the observer? Removing it should be done during the opposite action by the same class that adds the observer.

Comment: You pretty much need to subclass to use the notification system anyway. The selector that's called when the notification is posted has to be implemented by the object that's added as the observer, That could conceivably be done with a category, but usually you need a subclass for this.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you should think about what object is observing changes and make it appropriate. This usually means a controller class, and in this case you usually already have a custom subclass. It should usually be receiving the observation callbacks and forwarding them as required. It should add and remove itself as an observer when it is created / destroyed / put on display / removed from display.

That said, if you persist with making arbitrary classes observers, here's an idea (I think it should be safe, though I wouldn't want to rely on it):

You can use a single custom class to handle the removal of the observer. This should be a class which is configured with a reference to the class to be removed. During the configuration method this class adds itself to the class to be removed using `objc_setassociatedobject` and `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN`, and stores the pointer to the class to be removed in an `NSValue`. Then, when it is deallocated, it removes the other class from the notification center, using the `NSValue`.